# eclipse m2e: can't open declarations after importing maven projects

Tags: eclipse, import, m2e

Okay so the situation is simple so I'm not sure what the problem is and I've spent over three frustrating hours debugging with no luck!

I cloned a maven project from GitHub (using git) to ~/workspace/MyCompany/MyProject.

Then I did `File` -> `Import...` -> `Existing Maven Projects` and then selected MyProject as the root directory.

It appears like the import was a success but eclipse doesn't recognize any classes, even `String` and `ArrayList`! Whenever I right-click and choose `Open Declaration`, I get the following error message:

> Problems opening an editor. Reason: project_name does not exist.

I'm using eclipse Juno and m2e 1.2.0. m2e was installed via Help->Install New Software...

Comment: Well curses, finally find someone else who had same problem as me, and it's frigging unanswered. For me though, I did have this project working, then came back to it after sorting out some SVN projects. Googling this problem brings up lots of SVN issues... but I don't have any SVN plugins installed...

Comment: Ok, well turns out I'm not too smart. Well... maybe... Not sure what got my project into a stink, but by effectively starting over with a clean workspace I was able to import that maven project just fine. I did have sub-projects (what ever maven likes to call them) which initially I was not given the option to import... so maybe the link between them was lost? tl;dr delete everything and start over :D